# how to set button gradient color for textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I want to design a textbox and textarea with some gradients effects inside them look like the above img.

I find a way to set it on button.

But i was not able to fix it to a textarea.

Comment: attach examples of your CSS and HTML please

Comment: i just need the css for the background of textarea..

Comment: Will upload my css within few minutes. I deleted my previous ones

Comment: without examples my answer is it SHOULD work for both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this  [Ultimate Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) or [Css Portals](http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/text-box.htm). This will fullfill your need.

Hence you you have not inserted you css and html. We can do this far.

If you need code use the following

```
.gradient_effect{
    background: rgb(252,255,244); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%, rgba(223,229,215,1)     40%, rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(252,255,244,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(223,229,215,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(179,190,173,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(252,255,244,1) 0%,rgba(223,229,215,1) 40%,rgba(179,190,173,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    .text_box-border:double 5px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:8px; 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px; 
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #8c898c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #8c898c;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #8c898c;
}
```

Comment: excellent. Answer like this makes stackoverflow the best. After struggling for an hour, I got the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

```
textarea {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, black);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  red,  black);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#000000');
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EjFUd/

**Edit:** beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

```
​textarea {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 75%, rgb(230, 230, 230) 100%);
}​
```

Exmpl - http://jsfiddle.net/VSpB8/

for more css3 generators - http://css3gen.com/gradient-generator/

Answer (score 1):

Here try this : [note : adjust the color u want]

css:

```
#gradientTextarea  {
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f5f5f5 100%); / FF3.6+ /
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff),  color-stop(100%,#f5f5f5)); / Chrome,Safari4+ /
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); / Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ /
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); / Opera 11.10+ /
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); / IE10+ /
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#f5f5f5 100%); / W3C /
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f5f5f5',GradientType=0 );
 border:1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
```

html

```
<textarea id="gradientTextarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#gradient {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(0%, #ccc), color-stop(100%, #fff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #fff);
}
```

with `#grandient` as the id of the input box

use this one to generate your gradient: 
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/